# pyinstaller failing with permission error [Err-13]

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to create exe for my python file (test1.py), I'm execute the command 
`pyinstaller test1.py` (and also tried with few other pyinstaller options).
it is failing with below error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\testuser\\AppData\\Roaming\\pyinstaller\\bincache00_py37_32bit\\vcruntime140.dll'
```

I am not sure from where is is taking double backslashes.
even if i copy this path and try to open in windows explorer, it is not opening.
If I change double backslash with single backslashes - then i am able to open the path in windows explorer.

When try to access path with windows explorer (with double backslashes)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FYz9.png)

below with just changing double slash to single backslash
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faqNI.png)

any pointers ?

Comment: Have you tried running the command with an admin privileged CMD?

Comment: Yep, just tried.same error.  Opened CMD as admin.

Comment: Try to remove the whole folder and run Pyinstaller again. Also, make sure that the `vcruntime140.dll` exists in that path.

Comment: tried uninstalling pyinstaller and then installed again. Still same error.Also "vcruntime140.dll" path is created at run time and try to place the files.

Comment: Based on your images the `bincache00_py37_32bit` should have many data.  The access denied error means that the file doesn't exist. Are you sure that the file is there? can you provide another screenshot for contents of `bincache00_py37_32bit`?

Comment: No, there is only on file in this folder and that is - test1.exe.manifest. No other files exist in bincache00_py37_32bit folder. At which step files are coming in this directory.

Comment: It is a permission issue. can you try a [virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)? I think this should somehow work as it creates the Pyinstaller by your user.

Comment: Ok, now i set up venv and also installed python again from scratch. I encountered the same error, BUT this time i can see lot of files are created in same directory (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py37_64bit).Other files are with extension ".pyd", and error is coming for ".dll" extension file (api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll).Earlier it was not able to create any.Its quite random.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have writing rights in the folder you are trying to create the .exe file in. In the folder you want to create your .exe: Right-click, click properties, click security, and make your user has the right writing rights.

Comment: Hi, i am not able to reach to mentioned path with "double backslash", however zame path is accessible if i replace double backslash with single backslash. To me it seems like an issue because of double backslash (may be i am wrong)

Comment: No, the double backslashes have nothing to do with it. It's just how python specifies the path to the file. Have you tried changing folder rights in the folder: `C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py37_32bit` as specified above?

Comment: Hi, checked the security permission, they look ok.full access to user.However i also add more information in my initial question (with 2 images) to give more information.hope that will make it more clear.